# How to make a connection using windows authentication for working with multiple databases?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-authentication, sqlconnection

I previously used SQL connection for my SQL queries in C# like this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString =
"Data Source=our.server;" +
"User id=user_ID; " +
"Password=The_Pass; " +
"MultipleActiveResultSets = true";

conn.Open();
```

But it is not working when I want to work with multiple databases at once.

```
//just a very simplified representation of my very complicated query
string double_db_query = " select top 10 * into [DB_1].[dbo].[test_table] from [DB_2].[dbo].[source_table] "; 
using (SqlCommand double_db_command = new SqlCommand(double_db_query, conn)) 
{
double_db_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

It returns error because my connection is only connected to one of the databases
I have separate usernames and passwords for each DB and I can't be connected to two DB by SQL connection.
My windows account has access to all the databases but I don't know how to make a windows connection.
The samples that I have seen all include database name which shows they connect to only one database. Like in this link:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Can a windows authentication completely replace my SQL connection to be used in making commands?
Related question:
[Connecting to SQL Server using windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605533/connecting-to-sql-server-using-windows-authentication)

Comment: Have connection string stored in app or web config instead of having it hard coded. Have a separate con string for each different DB connection

Comment: When making a connection to a server, you always need to specify a database to connect to at the time. If, however, you need to reference multiple databases in a single query, you can use 3 part naming (like you have above), but you should endeavour to connect to the correct database if you only need to reference one.

Comment: You don't. A connection has one and only one "current" database and is associated with a specific identity. With windows authentication, you don't supply name and password - that comes from the current user of the machine. So you cannot use different identities for different connections.

Comment: Thank you. As I wrote and it can be seen in the query, my query works with different databases "```at once```".
I have heard that by windows authentication I can solve this problem but I don't know how.

Comment: But maybe you are confused about authentication methods. Your topic says windows authentication but it seems you really mean that provided by sql server. But if you need to run queries from the same application that use different databases, i think you need to think about how best to accomplish that. Using different identities within the same application seems to be a major obstacle and complication you are not ready to address.

Comment: The Database server would need a "Linked Server" to the second Server. Also you would need to setup a mapping of the users to use sql auth.

Comment: @SMor Yes, I know it's SQL connection and far from windows authentication but I just wrote what I know till know. I don't really have an idea of how windows authentication can replace what I do. You can read the last comments of this chat if you wish:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222371/discussion-on-question-by-iraj-a-sql-command-in-c-needs-to-connect-to-two-datab

Comment: @Larnu So you say there's no such a thing as windows authentication which connects my query to all the databases that my windows user has access to? In the chat that I mentioned (link above) some senior friends suggested that it is possible.

Comment: @Larnu You mean like what I do now? 
Then what can be the solution? Do you have any info about how to use windows authentication instead? (I hope the messages are not shifted to chat area)

Comment: *"If, however, you need to reference multiple databases in a single query, you can use 3 part naming (like you have above)"* I've already stated what you would do.

Comment: I think there is a lot of misunderstanding here. You cannot connect to two databases with one connection, unless they are on the same server. You need a connection to each database. You can put `Integrated Security=True;` into each connection string and set up Windows Authetication on your server(s), but you will stil have to handle the two connections independently.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry, I really don't know what "3 part naming" means. I don't have any idea. What I have written above doesn't work. Because I need to work with two databases and my connection only connects to one database.

Comment: *"I really don't know what "3 part naming" means"* Literally what it "says on the tin", there are 3 parts: `[DB_1].[dbo].[test_table]`, `DB_1`, `dbo` and `test_table`.

Comment: @PalleDue my different databases are on the same server. Can you please elaborate your reply in an answer post? This comment section has come to the end of capacity and will be shifted to chat section if we write more. I don't know how to set up windows authentication and I can't handle connections independently because the query deals with two DBs at once.

Comment: An object like a table has a 4 part name as [instancename].[databasename].[schemaname].[objectname].  The default instancename is the instance hosting the connection.  A different instancename can be used, but it requires a linked server.  Using a linked server requires caution.  The default database is the current database context.  The default schema depends upon the user...it might be the user or dbo.  The objectname is not optional.  Linking databases on the same server and on different servers is very different.

Comment: @Iraj `I have separate usernames and passwords for each DB` why? If you want to connect to multiple databases, use one account. It's as simple as that.

Comment: can you all please write answers in posts? I promise to vote up! This comment section is going to moved to the chat area. 
To @ Larnu: I got it. but that username is only valid to work with one of the databases and correct naming won't help in working with two.
@RandyinMarin DBs are on the same server and unfortunately I didn't understand other parts of the explanation on what exactly should I do now. Thanks.

Comment: @Iraj it's impossible to answer because you haven't explained what the problem is yet. Why do you have multiple accounts? Fix that. Use only one account

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is the organization of our company, defined by IT that each database has it's own separate username and password and now I wish to work with multiple databases at once and the SQL connection method doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @Iraj a company may dictate that the earth is flat. It's not. If you want to use multiple databases, you need one server login

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you. So, you mean Windows authentication can't help by this problem?
Do you have any idea about this guide by Microsoft? ```https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authentication-in-sql-server```

Comment: It *can*. Because it's a single account. That's both the most secure and easiest way to connect to a database,

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Then can you please help me by writing in a post how to implement it in practice? I will be really really thankful. I just hear some theoretic ideas about this topic since the last month but couldn't find a practical and clear solution. 
(this comment section will be moved to chat area soon.)

Answer (score 1):

For windows authentication you want to use what's called "integrated security".  You can search online for the term or go to the following for examples.  You don't specify either a user or password.  Something like "Trusted_Connection=True;" is used instead.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

The query from multiple database on the same instance is fine.  The account used to run the query must have the required permissions to both databases.  If you are not too worried about access, then you can map the windows account as users to both databases and add the user in each to db_owner.

You can do the same for a sql server login.  It can be mapped as users in both databases.  Granting permissions to databases is the same for Windows accounts/groups and for SQL Server logins.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen that page. I tried to replace those strings with my current connection string but it didn't work. I don't know how exactly I should implement what you explained.

Comment: What error did you get when trying it?  If you got a database specific permission error, I would consider that progress.

Comment: yeah in fact error is kinda new for this problem. I receive ```There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.``` which is related to when you use a data reader twice. I should investigate how I have to change the code for the new connection. My connection string is now: ```conn.ConnectionString="Server= our.server; Integrated Security=True;" ; ```

Comment: You have one using statement.  You can also use it on connection and reader objects to insure they are disposed.